# How to implement a Download button using Ajax and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to export some images in a Zip file and download it using Ajax and JQuery.

I recieve always a JavaScript error of "uncaught domexception failed to read the 'responsetext' property from 'xmlhttprequest' ".

**NB: the code below is only a try of pdf file**

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="DownloadFile">@PageRes["resExportImages"]</button>


<script>
        $('#DownloadFile').on('click', function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/172905/test.pdf',
                method: 'GET',
                xhrFields: {
                    responseType: 'blob'
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    var images = document.createElement('images');
                    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
                    images.href = url;
                    images.download = 'myfile.pdf';
                    images.click();
                    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: why do you want to use AJAX for this? It just adds a fairly pointless layer of indirection. Just make a hyperlink which points directly at the file to be downloaded. The browser will do the rest. All your code is doing now is faking a hyperlink and then trying to put the data into it as an object URL, because you can't directly download a file to the user's device via AJAX. You might as well just use a regular hyperlink to begin with. (If you want to make it look like a button, use CSS classes to do so.)

Comment: Hi @ADyson thanks for your reply, the AJAX was a suugest from my supervisor, I want really to export some banneers (image format) and download into a zip file when I click on the mentioned button, is it possible with using only css ?

Comment: CSS is just for defining visual styles in a HTML document. Did you mean by using JavaScript? See [these results](https://www.google.com/search?q=Javascript+create+zip+file+in+browser&oq=Javascript+create+zip+file+in+browser&aqs=chrome..69i57.5991j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) which will hopefully point you in the direction of creating a zip file client-side - I haven't used it by JSZip seems to be the thing to use. You'd have to use AJAX to download all the files you want to place into the ZIP, wait for them all to complete, and then create the zip and send it for download.

Comment: However there's a chance it'll be more efficient to do it server-side if you can.

Comment: yes that's what I mean it, I've already google it but I didn't get what I want that's why I opened it this question

Comment: well did you visit any of the links in the results I just posted? Have you tried to implement any of it? I don't know which bits you don't understand. What part (or parts) of this task specifically is proving a problem for you?

Comment: I am working on now, I am trying to follow a guide then I will let you know thanks